# Adjoint linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Is it the case that the adjoint of a matrix is just its transpose- the definition is based off inner products.
Does it matter whether it is a complex or real inner product?

Comment: The matrix corresponding to the adjoint of the transformation $x\mapsto Ax$ is $A^T$ if $A$ is real-valued and $A^\dagger$ if $A$ is complex valued.  $A^T$ here denotes the **transpose** while $A^\dagger$ denotes the **conjugate transpose**.

Comment: @gotit--thanks because...?

Comment: Those are the matrices $M$ we which solve $\langle x, My\rangle = \langle Ax, y\rangle$.  Try it yourself to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

For a linear transformation $T:V\to W$, the matrix of its adjoint $T^*:W^*\to V^*$ will be the (conjugate) transpose of its matrix if you’re using dual bases for the vector spaces. When you’re working in $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard basis and the usual Euclidean scalar product, which is what it looks like you’re asking about, this condition is satisfied.